# how to insert variables in command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts, password, vpn

I have the need to be able to enter or insert data in 3 input in the **command console** but in an automatic way. The first input is the one that is manifested when executing the **sudo** command where it asks for the password of the root user, the second input is an **HMA** user and the third input is the password of this user.

**The command:**

> echo password | sudo hma-vpn.sh -p tcp Texas | echo user | echo password

But the value of each input is not being entered because when executing it asks me for the **sudo** password something that it must have already entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo -S <command>`

`-S` to accept the password that you piped in via `echo`